# finite number of combinations with R

Tags: r, constraints, combinations

I need a suggestion on how to create a combination of elements with R.
More specifically, I have 37 elements (customer_ID represented by an univocal code). I need to generate 31 combinations of 33 elements out of those 37. In addition, I have a constraint: each of those 37 elements must be included in AT LEAST 28 combination.

Here's a snapshot of how data looks like:

```
Customer_ID 
1446    
1490    
1626    
1855    
1907    
2186    
2558    
2585    
2820    
3902
....
```

thanks in advance for helping me!

Comment: can you share the expected output using the snapshot data ?

Comment: @sachin2014 The expected output is a table 33 rows (elements) x 31 cols (combinations), so that each column represents a combination of 33 out of 37 elements. Each element (among 37) must appear in at least 28 columns.

Comment: maybe just `matrix(1:37, nrow=33, ncol=31)`?

Comment: That constraint might be impossible to achieve. I think the minimum you can have is 27.